# Is there a way to read & write a 2d array to a .db or .txt file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, store, fs

I am really new to this field just started my first project and instead of using complex data base's I just want to store a simple 2d array (table) to file so that I can retrieve it later, I did look at **fs.writeFile** but it doesn't seem to accept arrays in this format...

I am really new to this field so if there are any other ways of storing data or if this is a really bad way to store data then please suggest me what to do

```
var myArray = [
["bob","john","jack"],
[62,31,11],
["employed","unemployed","uneligible"],
["engineer","doctor","student"],
["21/09/2021","28/11/2021","16/12/2021"]]
```

how can I save this as it is to a file (any file) for later use

```
// something like this 

writeToFile( "./info.db" , myArray )

// inside the file info.db
[["bob","john","jack"],[62,31,11],["employed","unemployed","uneligible"],["engineer","doctor","student"],["21/09/2021","28/11/2021","16/12/2021"]]
```

and also to get this array back as an array , i did try using readFileSync with utf8 encoding but i got the data back as a buffer as such when i try to read the data[0] i get this the first character of the string " [ "

Answer (score 1):

This is because `fs.writeFile` accepts a *string* as the second argument. So we can instead `JSON.stringify` the data instead of writing the raw JS *object*.

```js
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');

var myArray = [
    ["bob","john","jack"],
    [62,31,11],
    ["employed","unemployed","uneligible"],
    ["engineer","doctor","student"],
    ["21/09/2021","28/11/2021","16/12/2021"]
];

writeFileSync('./info.db', JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Just in general, using JSON as a big database isn't a good practice because

- First of all, it is not *relational*
- It is not a DBMS, it is a data format.

Comment: so should i look at sqlite3 because i am using electron and i have to embed a database into the app its self, i just started this and getting my head around dbms and SQL language seems really hard, any suggestion on how to get started

Comment: and how do i read this data again , when i use readFilesync with utf8 i get the data back as a single string rather than an array

Comment: This is because it ends up with a string. For example you have `const data = readFileSync('./info.db')`, you have to `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: Using sqlite3 is a good option, at least for desktop apps. SQL isn't that hard. The syntax is pretty readable. Well, just try get started with sqlite3 and where ever you need help, StackOverflow is there :)

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helps you.